# Hide a circle along with the binded marker

Tags: google-maps, geometry, markermanager

I'm working with Google Maps v3 and I use the MarkerManager to hide the markers on a certain zoom level. I bind circle objects to these markers. Anyway, they aren't hided when the markers are. How can I bind the circles to hide with the markers?

The binding:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
});
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map, 
  radius: 50,
});
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
Array.push(marker);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you solved your problem? If not add this:

```
circle.bindTo('map', marker);
```