# Get a parameter from a binded element in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, bind, geometry, markermanager

Previously I [get an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923283/hide-a-circle-along-with-the-binded-marker) to the linking of an element. My next question is: how can I get the "radius" parameter of a binded circle, from the marker?

The code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
});
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map, 
  radius: 50,
});
circle.bindTo('map', marker);
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
Array.push(marker);
```

I need the cirlce's radius, which binded to the Array[x] marker. Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get a bound object from an object.

What you can do is set the circle as an object on the marker

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
});
var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map, 
  radius: 50,
});
marker.circle = circle; // Add the circle object to the map object
circle.bindTo('map', marker);
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
Array.push(marker);
```

Now you can get the radius with

```
Array[x].circle.getRadius();
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mRN2e/)

Comment: It's a good idea, solve my problem, thank you! Easy and smart :)